# How to port Windows Phone 7 application to iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, windows-phone-7

I would like to port a WP7 app I wrote to the iPhone. 
Is there some useful document for me to start? I have no knowledge in Objective-C yet.

Comment: While they don't address the specific case of coming from Windows Phone 7 (unsurprising, given how new the platform is), there are plenty of good getting-started resources in the questions [How-to articles for iPhone development, Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c) and [Are you doing iPhone development? How do you learn?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405568/are-you-doing-iphone-development-how-do-you-learn)

Comment: This will not be trivial... there is no direct mapping from Silverlight to the iPhone Objective C environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MonoTouch is a development stack for using C# and .NET to develop iOS apps. This should make iOS app development easier for existing .NET developers.

Here're the good parts of MonoTouch:

- Supports C# language
- Supports LINQ
- Silverlight core is supported (eg. .NET core, WebServices, JSON, XML). Read [MonoTouch FAQ](http://monotouch.net/faq) for more detail.
- Supports Sqlite (only) via Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll
- iOS classes exposed as .NET managed classes

There are a few gotchas:

- You can't dynamically link to an assembly. Code needs to be recompiled natively on the iOS (sorry no JIT compilation)
- Because MonoTouch still depends on the iOS SDK, you must be familiar with iOS programming model (eg. view hierarchy and application lifecycle model).
- You can't use VisualStudio directly. You need MonoDevelop and Xcode to develop MonoTouch apps. That said, someone apparently hacked Visual Studio and was able to write a large portion (not all) of the code in Visual Studio. Check it out [here](http://www.shrinkrays.net/code-snippets/csharp/monotouch-tips-and-snippets.aspx).

Because of this setup, I would recommend separating your code into business and UI logic. The business logic can be reused in iOS and WP7 projects, but develop the UI logic individually for iOS and WP7.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [Mono touch](http://monotouch.net/). It allows you to write native iPhone apps in C# so at least that way you only have one new thing to learn and that's iPhone framework Cococa Touch.

I personally found the [Pragmatic Programmers: iPhone SDK Development](http://pragprog.com/titles/amiphd/iphone-sdk-development) book a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you are familiar with html(5) and javascript you can think about using frameworks like [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) which supports up to 7 mobile plattforms using the same application code.